# Return one of two types of strings

Tags: python, class, return, return-value

I have a Python function which may return either one of two types of return values, `animal` or `food`. Both are string types. Right now, I differentiate between the two by always returning two values, asserting that only of them is `True`:

```
def help(x):
    if some_condition(x):
        return 'monkey', None
    elif # ...
        animal = some_fantasy_animal(x)
        return animal, None
    elif #..
        food = some_food_no_one_has_ever_heard_of(x)
        return None, food
    elif # ...
        return None, 'steak'
    # ...



def main():
    animal, food = help('ddd')
    if animal:
        assert(not food)
        # do something useful
        pass
    else:
        assert(food)
        # do something useful
        pass
    return
```

There must be a better way to handle this. What are the options?

Comment: what are animal and food?

Comment: In reality, strings that I use for building a config file. Depending on the type, they assume different roles. The `animal`-`food` metaphor is to abstract away this.

Comment: Are they instances of a class?

Comment: Yes, they are all `string`s.

Comment: Then just use isinstance

Comment: On what, the return value? It's always a `string`, right?

Comment: Ok I get what you are doing, I would use classes to differentiate your objects and make your life a lot easier.

Comment: Similar to what @Vor is suggesting?

Comment: I would probably make an "Animal" abstract class then inherit the methods etc.. subclassing your different "Animals"

Comment: if I were you, id start from scratch lol. right now youre using variable names to differentiate between what seem to be, as @PadraicCunningham mentioned, classes. Use classes. I would also separate the animal and food functions so that you always know what you're returning (this is good programming practice in general)

Answer (score 1):

Your scenario is kind of strange

You might want to create an Animal class and a Food class, and have them derive from some common base class. Then you can either use `isinstance` or better, forget the `if` conditions and call a method defined in the base class, which you can override for each type.

If there are no commonalities between Food and Animal, then you probably shouldn't have one function that can return either type.

Comment: A dictionary maybe ? keys would indicate the type. There seem to be multiple ways of doing it.

Comment: @Noob Yeah...you could use a dictionary to create a mapping between words and types. That might be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could create a set of animals and food like:

```
animals={'hippo', 'monkey'}
food={'bananas', 'steak'}
```

and then check with `in` operator:

```
h = help('ddd')

if h in animals:
    ...
elif h in food:
    ...
```

Comment: I cannot provide a comprehensive set of `food`s or `animal`s. They can assume any value, depending on `x`.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a solution. Representing the data as :

```
data = {'animal':['cat','dog'], 'food':['steak','egg']}
```

To check if a certain value `x` is an animal or food :

```
t = [k for k, v in data.iteritems() if x in data[k]]
```

`t` would then contain the class to which a particular item belongs. Note that if an `animal` is also present as a `food`, then `t` would contain both. Kind of flexible !

Comment: I cannot provide a comprehensive list of `food` or `animal`. They can assume any value, depending on `x`.

Comment: How do we know if a particular string is an animal or food ?

Comment: Well, `help()` knows. Exposing this information is the matter of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class that takes arguments an pass all the logic that is referring to determine the type inside:

for example:

```
class Result(object):
  def __init__(self, animal=None, food=None):
    self.animal = animal
    self.food = food 

  @property
  def is_animal(self):
    return self.animal != None

  @property
  def is_food(self):
    return self.food != None

def help(x):
  if x == 1:
    return Result(animal='monkey')
  elif x == 2:
    return Result(animal='hippo')
  elif x == 3:
    return Result(food='bananas')
  else:
    return Result()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  result = help(3)
  if result.is_animal:
    print result.animal
  if result.is_food:
    print result.food
```